# Find a general formula from piecewise-defined function (II)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

This question is very similar to my [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204055/how-can-i-find-a-general-formula-describing-this-piecewise-function). I have: $s \in [0;100]$ and $s \in Z$. The piece-wise definition is as follows:
$$20 \le s \le 100 \to 0\\
10 \le s \lt 20 \to 1\\
s \le 9 \to 2\\
$$

Following the previous question's answers my best try was this:

$\displaystyle f(s) = 2 - \left \lfloor \frac{s}{10} \right \rfloor + H \left (\left \lfloor \frac{s}{10} \right \rfloor - 3 \right ) \cdot \left ( \left \lfloor \frac{s}{10} \right \rfloor - 2 \right )$

where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside Step Function. That involves too many calculations. There must be something simpler, I'm just too blind to see it

Comment: You need to specify what functions can appear in the formula. For example, in C you could write something like (s <= 9 ? 2 : (s >= 10 && s < 20 ? 1 : 0)).

Comment: What is your objective exactly? Are you using this for a computer program or are you seeking a mathematical answer?

Comment: @copper.hat: I seek a mathematical answer, like those of my previous question. Allowed functions should be floor, ceil, heaviside step function. But if an answer formula contains some other functions I could accept it. It's difficult to say which one are allowed beforehand.

Comment: @EmmadKareem: See my previous comment.

Comment: A mathematical answer is a bit vague. For what purpose do you want such a formula? One formula could be in terms of characteristic functions, eg, $s \mapsto 1_{\{0,...,9\}}(s)+ 2 \cdot 1_{\{10,...,19\}}(s)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: Well I didn't even know such characteristic functions existed! I'd have called that definition piece-wise as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Discrete_form) of the Heaviside step function you may use for example :
$$f(s)=\left(2-\left \lfloor \frac s{10}\right \rfloor\right)\operatorname{H}(19-s)$$
or the simple :
$$f(s)=\operatorname{H}(9-s)+\operatorname{H}(19-s)$$

Comment: Aw, your second one was rather obvious, I feel stupid now :)

Comment: @rubik: Agreed (I was influenced by your divisions by $10$ first and had to get out of the attractor :-))

Answer (score 2):

$$f(s)=1-\text{sgn}(\lfloor s/10-1 \rfloor)$$

Comment: Interesing idea with the sign function!